# How to use Python's re.sub to match and replace group zero or more times?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
host = 'www.example.com'
urls = [
'auth_redirect_url = aaa.bbb.ccc.com/auth-web',
'auth_redirect_url = aaa.bbb.ccc.com'
]    
for url in urls:
    print re.sub(r'(^auth_redirect_url\s*=\s*)(.*)(/.*)', r'\g<1>{}\g<3>'.format(host), url)
```

I want to replace the host name 'aaa.bbb.ccc.com' to 'www.example.com', but the regex does not work, because the path in url may not exist. Is there a way to match a group 0 or more times? Or how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Is it for Python 2-3.4 or 3.5+? If the latter, you may add `?` after `(/.*)` - `(/.*)?`.

Comment: Python2.7, add `?` after `(/.*)` report error: unmatched group

Comment: Yes, that is right. A workaround is to limit the second group as is shown below. Or use a lambda inside re.sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second group could capture everything except `/`:

```
import re

host = 'www.example.com'
urls = [
    'auth_redirect_url = aaa.bbb.ccc.com/auth-web',
    'auth_redirect_url = aaa.bbb.ccc.com'
]

for url in urls:
    print re.sub(r'(^auth_redirect_url\s*=\s*)([^/]*)(.*)',
                 r'\g<1>{}\g<3>'.format(host), url)
```

Output:

```
auth_redirect_url = www.example.com/auth-web
auth_redirect_url = www.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you, really help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This method may help you

```
text_filtered = re.sub(r'<p ([^>]*)>', '<p>', text_filtered) # remove the other field from p tag
```